# Key mapping under XWayland (like earlier with xbindkeys )

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, wayland, shortcut-keys, 18.04

I use a mouse, a 3D-mouse and a keyboard with a lot of extra keys which are mapped via *xbindkeys* under Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. Now the support of 17.04 is run out and I was forced to switch over to Ubuntu which now uses the Gnome Shell again and additional based on *Wayland*. This sounds good but the important feature provided by *xbindkeys* seemed not to be supported anymore as described in this [blog](https://cubethethird.wordpress.com/2017/06/07/mixed-feelings-about-wayland-on-gnome/).

What is now the proposed alternative way to map extra keys under *XWayland*?

Comment: You should be able to select xorg session at the login screen. Wayland is not exactly ready for prime time, so much so, that 18.04 will default to xorg.

Comment: You say, it can be assumed, that XWayland will support this feature in the feature too?

Comment: No, I didn't say that.

Comment: I currently test 18.04 and it runs very good. And faster than earlier. Here per default XWayland runs.

Comment: So, if all is dandy, why ask here?

Comment: Because explecitely this does not work...

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, in case someone needs a quick recipe for swapping keys on Wayland (done on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

I've got a dumb layout on my notebook keyboard, and needed to swap the "right shift" and the "?" keys. So, following the advice from https://askubuntu.com/a/1023182/976363 I simply edited `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` as root, swapping the keycodes for both keys.

```
    <RTSH> = 62;
    ...
    <AB11> = 97;
```

became

```
    <RTSH> = 97;
    ...
    <AB11> = 62;
```

The actual key labels depend on your keyboard layout, which should be looked up in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`.