# How to remap caps lock to esc in Ubuntu 17.10 and terminator?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.10, keyboard-layout, vim

I want to remap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> on my Ubuntu 17.10 laptop.

I have tried this method: [How to remap key in Ubuntu 17.10 Wayland? (Up key to Shift)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929744/how-to-remap-key-in-ubuntu-17-10-wayland-up-key-to-shift), this method: https://linuxcommando.blogspot.ca/2008/03/remap-caps-lock-key-for-virtual-console.html, and this method: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap to no avail.

Neither work, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is still <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

How do I remap these keys system wide? It's dead simple in OSX, there is a setting in system preferences to make <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> and that's it, it works in every app. Is there anything similar in Ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same as tranfuria's answer but on command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:escape']"
```

Comment: Is there a way to persist this change? It appears to be gone after a system update through `apt dist-upgrade`.

Comment: @k0pernikus: It should be persistent. Please ask a new question if you found otherwise.

Comment: use `"['caps:swapescape]"` in case you want to preserve capslock too.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the Gnome-tweak-tool, assuming you're running on gnome, if you're on unity, there is a unity-tweak-tool. Both can be installed using apt:

`sudo apt-get update`

&&

`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

OR

`sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`

in the gnome tweak tool under 'Keyboard & Mouse' there is an option called 'Additional Layout' options, in here you can change capslock key behavior, mapping it to esc, as well as just about anything you want.

Here is a picture as to what it might look like
[image: Gnome Tweak Tool]

Comment: Great, thank you. I wish there was a way to do it via the command line (I use Ansible to setup new machines), but this is much better than nothing!

Comment: @springloaded: Of course there is a command line way to do it too. I showed it in an alternative answer.

Comment: Unfortunately in gnome-tweak-tool 3.28.1 this option is removed.

Comment: @lz96: No it's not.