# Change 'Home' key to 'Escape' key

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I do not have an escape key on my new keyboard. Instead I have a <kbd>Home</kbd> key, similar to Mac keyboards. I would simply like to turn this <kbd>Home</kbd> key into an effective <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. I would not like to change anything else. I would also like this solution to be permanent.

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (64-bit).

Here are the links that I have already tried (very carefully, step by step) without success:

- [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)
- [How to remap caps lock to esc in Ubuntu 17.10 and terminator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007816/how-to-remap-caps-lock-to-esc-in-ubuntu-17-10-and-terminator)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is create a custom keyboard definition with the <kbd>Home</kbd> key mapped to <kbd>Esc</kbd>. See if this [Ubuntu documentation on customizing keyboard layout](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) can help.